# Math.NET Numerics - How to represent missing or invalid values?

Tags: math.net

Does the library have some way to represent missing or invalid values in vectors and matrices? A good reference is [Numpy masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To represent a missing or invalid data (or any kind of data you can not trust) you can use `double.NaN`. In that sense you can not trust any values obtained from that data. Those untrusted values will be `double.NaN` too.

```
var d = double.NaN;
var A = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,]
{
    { d, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
});
var B = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,]
{
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, d, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
});

Console.WriteLine(A*B);
```

Gives:

```
DenseMatrix 3x3-Double
NaN  NaN  NaN
  0  NaN    0
  0  NaN    1
```